# Auto js file is created while updating a css file as the same name while using atom editor

Tags: javascript, css, atom-editor

Every time while I am updating my css file and hitting cmd+s it saves the file and at the same time a js file is created underneath it in the same name as the css file, I am using Atom editor and am afraid that I might have installed any package thats causing this problem, how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue but only on one of my computers and I found that the difference between them was that I had 'language-javascript-jsx' on the atom instance giving me the issue. After disabling it and restarting, the problem went away.